# I can't use my HP Deskjet 2050 scanner

Tags: printing, scanner

I have a HP Deskjet 2050, I installed it's driver and I think it worked ( I doesn't have ink to test), but I just wanted to use it's scanner and I can't find how to do it. There's already another thread about this printer but i couldn't find any information about scanning.

Comment: look at this [GUIDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried the stuff in the guide but it didn't work :(

Comment: I have the same the same problem with my F4180 but do not have solved it yet. Will tell you if any progress